# If you are shooting a movie/photo (non-profit or profit) with a willing person, should you get a contract signed from him/her?

Tags: film, legal, business, contracts, movie

I was wondering should you get a contract signed from the person who is interested in participating in the shooting as a subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you need a model release?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/when-do-you-need-a-model-release)

Answer (score 2):

**YES**

Whenever possible you should get a model release (or a contract with a model release clause) from anyone who appears in your photos or video, this can save a lot of trouble in the future and has no downside.

Comment: +1 and funnily enough I've just done exactly that - I've shot and am just about to deliver work for the UK charity Barnardo's who supplied their own model releases.  Also don't forget to get documentation for your engagement with the client (even if you're donating your services.)

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

If you do not have a release (for property, too.) your images are unusable. You cannot display them in public. You cannot use them in your portfolio. You cannot use them.

*ONLY* EXCEPTION: I worked as a news photographer—anything goes.

Comment: Is there any license you have get to become a news photographer?

Comment: @KirkHammett Press credentials. Assignments from your news director or a go-ahead if you stumble upon anything. It doesn't take long before you become a known quantity.

Comment: This is not true, at least in America. If you're in public, you do not have the expectation of privacy, and as such, people can photograph you as they please. A model release is still a good idea, as a specious lawsuit repellent, if nothing else, but nevertheless.

Comment: @FakeName it's more to do with libel.  My simple rule of thumb for a model release is to ask if I'm assigning that person a viewpoint (such as endorsing a product, service or person) if you are then you need one.

Comment: @FakeName Read the answer again. You've misinterpreted it. Nothing was said about what you CAN photograph. I was establishing that you MAY not use them after capture for any reason than to take up space. They are illegal for your USE without permission from the identifiable and recognizable owner of the identity, or property. This is especially true in the litigious United Snakes of America.

Comment: @FakeName If I agreed with you, we'd both be wrong.